# Alignment of text left and center

Tags: align

How could I correct the alignment

```
\begin{align*}
    &1 \text{ stg } = 0.5 \quad 
    P(A \mid A) = a \quad 
    P(B \mid B) = b \\
    &P(B \mid A) = (1-a) \quad 
    P(A \mid B) = 1-b
\end{align*}
```

I desire '1 stg = 0.5' to be on the same line but aligned left

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you want something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
1\,\text{stg} = 0.5 \qquad
\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
    P(A \mid A) &= a     &\qquad P(B \mid B) &= b \\
    P(B \mid A) &= (1-a) &\qquad P(A \mid B) &= 1-b
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 :-) For the unitiated reader(s) of this answer: Technically, only one of the two instances of `\qquad` within the `alignedat` environment is really needed; the other is redundant. Of course, having two instances of `\qquad` doesn't doesn't hurt, and it arguably makes the code easier to read and understand.